# Postfix email delist blacklisted IP from route

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, postfix-mta, blacklist

I'm using an AWS server for hosting a website. I've Postfix enabled to send emails from here itself. The emails are getting delivered to all except a particular domain. When we speak to the email provider team, they say that your emails are being routed from a Google IP (209.85.220.181) and that IP is blacklisted.

Do we really have any control on the network route of the emails sent? Can I specify my packet to never take the route of this IP? Is this an AWS problem? Please help.

Comment: Can't think of a reason why your setup would be sending mails via google's IP other than you being using google's service as an external smtp server. Are you sending mail via postfix with any additional wrapper like node-mailer? Also, can you mention what error code postfix receives from their server?